# Install jquery.min.js with bower

Tags: bower, bower-install

When installing a dependency with `bower`, how would I get the minified version of the target dependency?

Say I wanted to install `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` with `bower` what would be the command for that?

Answer (score 1):

Since the minified version of jquery is install as well when running `bower install jquery`, you can override the main file it points to, and point it to the minified jquery file.

If you look in the bower.json of bower_components/jquery the main file is:

```
"main": "dist/jquery.js"
```

You can override the main file in your projects bower.json by adding:

```
  {
    "overrides": {
      "jquery": {
        "main": "dist/jquery.min.js"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore Grunt (JS task runner).
Bower is for dependencies management, while Grunt is designed to act on these dependencies (you can compile CSS, do tasks like minification and concat, etc). There’s a Grunt module called “grunt-bower-task” that facilitates integrating the two. Enjoy! :)